# onCheckedChanged not called on AppCompatCheckBox view

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-checkbox, oncheckedchanged

I create some custom checkbox views dynamically in code. Those checkboxes inherit from AppCompatCheckBox.

```
public class ChangeableSelectionParameterValueCheckbox extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
```

I add the OnCheckChangedListener in code. 
The added OnCheckedChangeListener is a `android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;`

```
changeableSelectionParameterValueCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                //on checked changed code here
            }
        });
```

**The problem: onCheckedChanged is never called.** The custom checkbox seems to be not clickable.

**When I change my custom view class to inherit from android.widget.CheckBox, everything works fine.**

Any suggestions?

Comment: why do you need AppCompatCheckBox when CheckBox can do the same task

Comment: I don't really need it, but Android Studio gives me an error lint message saying 'this custom view should extend android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckbox instead'. And because I don't immediately see any particular changes to the onCheckedChange code in this AppCompatCheckbox class, I'm wondering why this is not working any more in this class.

Comment: And I expect that my app behaviour stays the same if I change my class to inherit from AppCompatCheckbox instead of Checkbox (as android studio suggests). But that's not the case. That's why I'm asking the question, but apparently it is worth a downvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by setting the property "clickable" to true.
It worked both in code and in XML, so choose one of these solutions:

```
AppCompatCheckbox check;
check.setClickable(true);
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             android:id="@+id/id_checkbox"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                             android:clickable="true"
                                             android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```